# Convert OData to sql string

Tags: c#, sql, linq, odata

Looking for some solution that will help me translate Odata queries to sql syntax string.

Basically I would like to use System.Linq.Dynamic that allows to pass a sql like string to where clause.

I was also trying to use ODataUriParser.ParseFilter that returns AST FilterClause but I do not know how to apply it to an entity framework table to limit results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably you are going in wrong direction, take a look at this.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint     Entity Framework already has Odata Context, why not use that one.

Answer (score 2):

Random package found on the Internet :)

[DynamicOData](https://github.com/danderson00/DynamicOData)